# Why not conditional noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, noexcept

The standard library doesn't typically use conditional noexcept. It is described in [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf):

> Each library function having a wide contract, that the LWG agree cannot throw, should be marked as unconditionally noexcept.

> If a library swap function, move-constructor, or move-assignment operator is conditionally-wide (i.e. can be proven to not throw by applying the noexcept operator) then it should be marked as conditionally noexcept. **No other function should use a conditional noexcept specification.**

But no reason is given.

Why?

Comment: The authors of **n3279** are Alisdair Meredith and John Lakos, and their emails are cited in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

**Background**: the presentation of changes in n3279 only implicitly lists the main actual change:

*Functions that don't have a wide contract shouldn't have an unconditional noexcept specification*.

This is the cause of most of the changes (so any function with a Requires-clause should clearly not be noexcept).

The reason is described in n3248: you cannot use exceptions to internally test pre-conditions if the function specifies that it is noexcept (since the exception cannot be caught - not even in debug-builds, one of the suggested options in n3248 was to allow a debug-mode to catch them).

**So what about conditional noexcept?**

The background doesn't explain why a few conditional noexcept without a Requires-clause were removed, but it indicated a general move away from potentially excessive noexcept and n3248 also states:

> **What are the risks associated with noexcept?**
>
> Unfortunately the feature
> is so new that there is very little field experience to develop a
> coherent set of guidelines. The risk from overly aggressive use of
> noexcept specifications is that programs with hidden terminate calls
> are produced. The risk of under-specifying noexcept specifications is
> that they become difficult to add in a later revision of the standard,
> as the noexcept operator becomes an observable part of the ABI.

Thus it seems that keeping a few conditional noexcept wasn't deemed worth those risks, compared to the benefits it would bring.

Comment: Can you explain why swap function, move-constructor, or move-assignment operator can be marked as conditional noexcept?